# How do I update devDependencies with latest version using NPM command?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I want to update devDependencies with latest version using NPM command.

`npm update` will update the packages in `dependencies` and npm update --save-dev this will add the latest dependencies in local module.

My concern is -

I want to check the latest version available. `npm-check-updates` 
Then I want to update one by one.

```
$ npm install -g npm-check-updates
$ npm-check-updates -u
$ npm install
```

One more question what component I can update easily without affecting the project.. Please guide me.

My Package.json:

```
{
  "author": {
    "name": "Test",
    "company": "Test"
  },
  "name": "Test",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "10.0.010",
  "devDependencies": {
    "expect.js": "~0.2.0",
    "glob": "~3.2.7",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.5",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.4",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^0.2.1",
    "grunt-git-describe": "~2.3.2",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.8.3",
    "grunt-ngmin": "0.0.3",
    "grunt-string-replace": "~0.2.4",
    "grunt-usemin": "^2.1.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.5",
    "karma": "~0.12.21",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.2.5",
    "karma-coveralls": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-expect": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha": "~0.1.4",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.1",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
    "mocha": "~1.16.1",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.14",
    "rjs-build-analysis": "0.0.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.2.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test",
    "coveralls": "grunt karma:coveralls && rm -rf ./coverage"
  },
  "license": "Test",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-rename": "0.0.3",
    "grunt-jscs-checker": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-sync": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.3",
    "sinon": "1.14.1"
  }
}
```

My project is very huge project. I can not update all in one shot. I have to update one by one and I have to test.

Please suggest better way to do this..

Comment: "grunt-contrib-less": "latest",

Comment: @cbass  npm update -D will update all.. I want to check all and update one by one only..

Comment: @Ved can you guide me what else I can update directly without any worry ? without affecting project code..

Comment: instead of version, just put "latest". it will get latest version according to the registry.

Comment: If you upadate. it may conflict with current code. It will be better to visit the repository and see what is new in the current version

Comment: any command for updating one by one.. please share.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99895/discussion-between-ved-and-javascript-coder).

Comment: Can we discuss this in chat ??

Comment: Can I update karma modules.. It will work with exsisting project? or any issue will be there..